# OUT or INOUT parameter not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, arguments, out

If I create a stored procedure in MySQL with an OUT or INOUT parameter, it does not work.  Even if I leave the stored procedure empty.  The DDL is as follows:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testing_inout`(`a` int,INOUT `b` int)
BEGIN

END
```

The first parameter is a regular IN parameter.  The second one is an INOUT paremeter (even if set as OUT the same problem persists)

When I call this stored procedure, I get an error stating:

> OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine db_name.testing_inout is not a
>   variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger.

This error persists even if code is written inside the stored procedure.  I am running mysql version 5.1.41.

This is a big problem for me because I cannot output the result of a recursive stored procedure because of this error.

Comment: You should probably show the statement that calls the procedure.

Comment: I don't think problem is with SP but the `BEFORE` trigger from where SP is being called.

Comment: I agree that the problem must be with the BEFORE trigger from where the SP is being called.  This error is happening when I run the SP via Navicat.  But when I call the SP from another SP, I do not get the error.  Conclusion: the way the run button of Navicat calls SP's is not working well with OUT and INOUT arguments.

Answer (score 4):

it works for me

```
mysql> CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testing_inout`(`a` int,INOUT `b` int)
    -> BEGIN
    -> 
    -> END
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

The second parameter because it's inout it need to be a variable:

```
mysql> set @c:=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> call testing_inout(1,@c);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

if you try this it will return 1:

```
delimiter |
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testing_inout`(`a` int,INOUT `b` int)
BEGIN
select b;
END
|
delimiter ;

mysql> call testing_inout(1,@c);
+------+
| b    |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The OP says: *‘When I **call** this stored procedure, I get an error’*. The issue may not be with the definition at all.

Comment: @prince: Yes, this works for jcho360, and jcho360 has demonstrated *what* works for them. But you are *not* showing what isn't working for you in *your* situation. I mean, you haven't yet shown us the statement(s) that call(s) your stored procedure.